# C++ MFC error C2664

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, c2664

I'm trying to make a simple window using c++ and mfc. the following code is taken from the book "Visual C++ and MFC Fundamentals" but it doesn't work. I get error C2664:BOOL  CFrameWnd::Create(LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR, ... )  cannot convert argument 2 from const char[20] to LPCTSTR. how can I change the code in order for it to work?

```
#include <afxwin.h>
class CSimpleFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
CSimpleFrame()
{
// Create the window's frame
Create(NULL, "Windows Application");
}
};
struct CSimpleApp : public CWinApp
{
BOOL InitInstance()
{
// Use a pointer to the window's frame for the application
// to use the window
CSimpleFrame *Tester = new CSimpleFrame ();
m_pMainWnd = Tester;
// Show the window
m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
return TRUE;
}
};
CSimpleApp theApp;
```

Comment: `Create(NULL, _T("Windows Application"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably building your application with Unicode character set (which is the default setting). Change the offending line to:

```
Create(NULL, _T("Windows Application"));
```

Depending on character set, `_T` expands either to nothing (MBSC), or to `L` (Unicode) which results in [wide character string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se784sk6.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If character set doesn't really matter to you and want to get rid of this kind of errors "forever", you could go to `Project Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `General` -> `Character Set`, and set it to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`. If not, `_T()` and/or `L` are your friends (depending on your character set settings)